# Can't download resized image from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-extensions

I'm using Firebase's Resize Images extension to automatically make thumbnails for my uploaded images

the problem is that the generated resized images don't have an Access token

I can't even see the resized image from the storage console until I manually click on "Create new access token"

[image]

Comment: I linked your question to a duplicate with the best (but still not great answer). Also see these search results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-extensions%5D+image+download

Comment: I already read all these questions, there is no working answer yet

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the linked question is not even related to mine, I can get download Url

Comment: What's the access token that you're referring to in that case? What are you trying to do (code-wise) with the generated images that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm trying to view the resized image from an Android app, the resized image can't be viewed from Firebase console nor downloaded from the app until i press on Create new access token (check the uploaded picture)

storage.DownloadFile( "/public/" & ImgName & "_80x80.jpg")

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that (fails to) download the data from Storage? Note that the [Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) as far as I know it has no `DownloadFile` method, so be sure to unwrap whatever wrapper method you use, or include it in the code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i solved it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072882/cloud-functions-resized-images-not-loading/61023298#61023298
I'm no expert in cloud functions but this fixed my issue kindly tell me if it has any side effects on the function

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause. You might want to report the issue on the [Extensions repo](https://github.com/firebase/extensions), and see what they have to say. In fact, I have the feeling some of these issues might already cover this: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/search?q=Access+token&type=Issues

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen [1] Voting to reopen since the OP stated that the linked duplicate did not help. [2] Alternatively, as a better approach, is it possible for you to change the duplicate to the one that the OP stated did solve the issue: [Cloud Functions: Resized images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59072882/2985643)? Either way, as things stand the reason for closure seems incorrect to me.