# How to get downloadURL of an existing image from firebase storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I pushed an image to firebase storage and by using Resize Images Extension, I am able to get a resized image of the same image name plus _240x320. To be clear with you I get the downloadURL of the original image, but I am not understand why I cannot get the downloadURL of the resized image. Here is my code:

```
func storeImageInFirebase(){
   let storeageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
   let imageName = UUID().uuidString //+ ".jpg"
   let imagesReference = storeageRef.child("images").child(imageName + ".jpg")
   let imageData = self.imgView.image!.pngData()
   let metaData = StorageMetadata()

   var imageName2 = imageName //+ "_240x320.jpg"
   let imagesReference2 = storeageRef.child("images").child(imageName2 + "_240x320.jpg")

   metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
   imagesReference.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData){ (metadate, error)
       in
       guard metadate != nil else{
           print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
           return
       }
      // Fetch the download URL
       imagesReference.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error)
           in
           if error != nil {
               print("Faild to download url:", error!)
               return
           }else{
               // show the url in real database
            print("resized image url ..... \(url?.absoluteString)")
            var theUsedURL = self.imgURL = (url?.absoluteString)!
            self.sendDataToFirebase()

           }
       })

        // Fetch the download URL
         imagesReference2.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error)
         in
         if error != nil {
         print("Faild to download url:", error!)
         return
        }else{
         // show the url in real database
         print("resized image url ..... \(url?.absoluteString)")
         self.imgURL2 = (url?.absoluteString)!
         self.sendDataToFirebase()

         }
     })
   } 
}
```

I wrote two image references, one for the original image and the other one for resized image. I am able to get the original image, but I have error faild to download url and the image does not exist for the resized image, where I can see in the Firebase Storage that the image there. I am trying to solve this from a weeks I will appreciate any help.

Comment: The data being uploaded is from imageData per `let imageData = self.imgView.image!.pngData()` and then `imagesReference.putData(imageData!`. It doesn't appear you're creating image2 (the one with reduced size) nor uploading anywhere in the code, therefore you won't have a downloadUrl to it. Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Jay I am using firebase Resize Images Extension and in default when I upload an image I will have a resize image in storage beside the original image, so there is no need to putData. what I want is to get the downloadURL for the resized image not the original image.

Comment: My apologies. Of course the second wont print because there's an error. I believe this may be a token issue. There's a [gitub #140](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/140) that's been around for a while and a possible fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072882/cloud-functions-resized-images-not-loading)

Comment: I solved the token issue, nothing change @Jay

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the Firebase Console->Storage showing the two files? Also, to keep the comments cleaned up, you can delete the errors you included in comments since they are now in the question

Comment: Try this; See if the reduced file url can be downloaded independently from the code in your question. In other words, hard code a file name `let imagesReference = storeageRef.child("images").child("test.jpg")` and create separate code that downloads only the reduced url `test_240x320.jpg` but is run manually from a button, after the code in the question is run. I wonder if there's an asynch issue going on whereas the second file hasn't been written before the code in the question attempts to get it. Oh. Isn't the reduced file going to have the same URL as the original, just a different name?

Comment: @Jay yes, it has the same URL as the original, and same name with only this addition _240x320 at the end. let's say my original image is test.jpg so my resized image will be test_240x320.jpg

Comment: Are you able to download it independently using the same code but without downloading the first file?